# Escaping quotes in string

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I have a python dictionary e.g.:

```
[{"pk":"1","name":"John","size":"1/4" "},{},{},etc]
```

That size is 1/4 inch,how would I "escape" that quote? So it still would display it as 1/4",

Its a list of things, so I cant just manually code it like `1/4\"`,
I tried `replace('"','\"')`

EDIT:
The orginal list is a textfield in my Django models:

```
[{'pk': '91', 'size': '', 'name': 'Thread Flat For BF', 'quantity': '2'}, {'pk': '90', 'size': '', 'name': 'Blade Holders Straight ', 'quantity': '26'},{'size':'3"','name':'2m 1/4" Round bar', 'quantity':'43'},{'size':'5','name':'2m 1/8" Round bar', 'quantity':'4'}]
```

Next step I have to prepare the list for jQuery, so I replace like this so its in the correct syntax for json.
mat_list =  manufactured_part.material_list.replace("'",'"')

Then I have this list:

```
[{"pk": "91", "size": "", "name": "Thread Flat For BF", "quantity": "2"}, {"pk": "90", "size": "", "name": "Blade Holders Straight ", "quantity": "26"},{"size':"3"","name':"2m 1/4" Round bar", "quantity":"43"},{"size":"5","name":"2m 1/8" Round bar", "quantity":"4"}]
```

So now the list is sent to the template and I loop through it with jquery, but the list is broken because of the " in the strings.

SO...I need to escape those " for the list to work, otherwise it has an obvious syntax error.

Hope this makes sense now.

Thanks

Comment: What are you *really* trying to ask?

Comment: Im asking how I would have that list intact with the " inch sign

Comment: Why you are not able to prepare data before adding to your dictionary?

Comment: is it an existing list you're trying to work with, or defining your own?

Comment: Yeah, no. Go back a step or two and [explain what you're really trying to accomplish](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: I am a little confused by your question. Can you give a more clear input and output that you wish? I just have no idea what do you really want.

Comment: The answer number 2 is correct.

Comment: json.dumps(string_w_quotes) is the way to go. See following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18886842/1141215

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to escape your backslash in the replace in order to get it printed. Try

```
replace('"','\\"')
```

Comment: thanks, I made it replace('"','\"'), Now it works with your solution

Comment: Be carful with that. E.g. setting the example string ```foo='hurr"durr\\'``` using ```print('string is "%s"' % foo.replace('"','\\"'))``` will print ```string is "hurr\"durr\"```, ```print('foo="%s"' % foo.replace('"','\"'))``` becomes ```string is "hurr"durr\"```.

Comment: @luckydonald you're right but it's possible to avoid the problem with lookbehind testing for backslash, something like re.sub(r"(?<!\\)'","\\'", foo)

Comment: Perhaps crucial details were missing from question when answered, but this answer is bad advice - there is no point in the OP writing their own buggy json serializer when a good one already exists in the stdlib

Comment: Why double slash?

Comment: @stema Thanks a lot! I was doing with one slash. Very confusing, why double slash works instead of one?

Comment: Necromantically speaking, I think the double backslash is necessary because `replace` sees a single backslash as a literal character. To convert a target character from a literal to a "special" character, we precede the target -- which in this case happens to be a backslash -- with a backslash.

Answer (score 6):

Using

`shlex.quote("string")`

or

`pipes.quote("string")`

Depending on the python version worked for me.

You can check here more details

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/shlex.py#L281

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to do it the hard way. Let Django [serialize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects) the query set for you.

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> I have to prepare the list for jQuery

So I assume you are trying to output Python objects in string form into a template file, transformed so that the output string is valid Javascript code.

This is equivalent to serializing them as JSON.

This is a solved problem, instead of replacing single quotes with double quotes etc yourself just do this:

```
import json

my_python_data = [{'pk': '91', 'size': '', 'name': 'Thread Flat For BF', 'quantity': '2'}, {'pk': '90', 'size': '', 'name': 'Blade Holders Straight ', 'quantity': '26'},{'size':'3"','name':'2m 1/4" Round bar', 'quantity':'43'},{'size':'5','name':'2m 1/8" Round bar', 'quantity':'4'}]

str_to_output_in_js_template = json.dumps(my_python_data)
```

This will handle all the escaping for you and ensure that the result is a valid Javascript object.

Comment: and then you have to escape single quotes

Comment: @pstanton yes but only if you are hand-writing the object literals

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, I used a python inbuilt escaping method.
something like this helped me

```
[{"pk":"1","name":"John","size":"1/4\" "},{},{},etc]
```

Ref:-

> http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals