# Replace all quotes in a string with escaped quotes?

Tags: python, string, replace

Given a string in python, such as:

```
s = 'This sentence has some "quotes" in it\n'
```

I want to create a new copy of that string with any quotes escaped (for further use in Javascript). So, for example, what I want is to produce this:

```
'This sentence has some \"quotes\" in it\n'
```

I tried using `replace()`, such as:

```
s.replace('"', '\"')
```

but that returns the same string. So then I tried this:

```
s.replace('"', '\\"')
```

but that returns double-escaped quotes, such as:

```
'This sentence has some \\"quotes\\" in it.\n'
```

How to replace `"` with `\"`?

UPDATE:

I need as output from this copyable text that shows both the quotes and the newlines as escaped.  In other words, I want to be able to copy:

```
'This sentence has some \"quotes\" in it.\n'
```

If I use the raw string and `print` the result I get the correctly escaped quote, but the escaped newline doesn't print. If I don't use `print` then I get my newlines but double-escaped quotes. How can I create a string I can copy that shows both newline and quote escaped?

Comment: I might be missing something, but your second `s.replace()` seems to be the same as the first.

Comment: Your last replace is correct. Try `print`ing the string and see what happens

Comment: I'm pretty sure `'This sentence has some "quotes" in it\n'` is a valid Javascript string literal.

Comment: Are you sure you just want to replace quotes? Backslashes, backspaces, and all sorts of other weird crap usually need escaping too. `repr(s)` catches a lot more things, though I don't know whether the result is always valid Javascript; it definitely isn't for unicode strings. json may also be worth looking into.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Hi usually when working with Javascript I use the json module provided by Python. It will escape the string as well as a bunch of other things as user2357112 has pointed out.

```
import json
string = 'This sentence has some "quotes" in it\n'
json.dumps(string) #gives you '"This sentence has some \\"quotes\\" in it\\n"'
```

Comment: this is nice and almost works for me, but it doesn't escape single quotes. i can swap them out myself, but I find it strange that it doesn't do it already.

Comment: `json.dumps()` doesn't have to escape single quotes because they don't have special meaning in json.  Remember, json is only a subset of JavaScript.  http://json.org/

Comment: @mix You don't need to escape single-quotes if they are within a double-quoted string. While Javascript supports single-quoted strings, all strings in JSON are double-quoted, so `json.dumps` will never need to escape single-quotes as it outputs all strings in double-quotes.

Answer (score 29):

Your second attempt is correct, but you're getting confused by the difference between the `repr` and the `str` of a string.  A more idiomatic way of doing your second way is to use "raw strings":

```
>>> s = 'This sentence has some "quotes" in it\n'
>>> print s
This sentence has some "quotes" in it

>>> print s.replace('"', r'\"')  # raw string used here
This sentence has some \"quotes\" in it

>>> s.replace('"', r'\"')
'This sentence has some \\"quotes\\" in it\n'
```

Raw strings are WYSIWYG:  backslashes in a raw string are just another character.  It is - as you've discovered - easy to get confused otherwise ;-)

Printing the string (the 2nd-last output above) shows that it contains the characters you want now.

Without `print` (the last output above), Python implicitly applies `repr()` to the value before displaying it.  The result is a string that would produce the original if Python were to evaluate it.  That's why the backlashes are doubled in the last line.  They're not in the string, but are needed so that if Python were to evaluate it each `\\` would become one `\` in the result.

Comment: I need the string to appear with the escaped quotes but also with the escaped newline. IOW, I want copyable output to look like: `'This sentence has some \"quotes\" in it.\n'`. If I use the raw string and print the result I get  the correctly escaped quote, but the escaped newline doesn't print. If I don't use `print` then I get  my newlines but double-escaped quotes.

Comment: Then you just need to do another replace, like `.replace("\n", r"\n")`.  That replaces the newline character with the two characters backslash and letter n.  If you also have other things you need to escape, this approach will get tedious ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Your last attempt was working as you expected it to.  The double backslashes you see are simply a way of displaying the single backslashes that are actually in the string.  You can verify this by checking the length of the result with `len()`.

For details on the double backslash thing, see: [`__repr__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

---

UPDATE:

In response to your edited question, how about one of these?

```
print repr(s).replace('"', '\\"')
print s.encode('string-escape').replace('"', '\\"')
```

Or for python 3:

```
print(s.encode('unicode-escape').replace(b'"', b'\\"'))
```