# replace double quotes with '\"' in python

Tags: python

I have a string -

```
l = '{"a": "1", "b": "2"}'
```

I want to convert this string to -

```
'{\"a\": \"1\", \"b\": \"2\"}'
```

For this I am trying to replace " with \"

Here's what I have tried -

```
l.replace('\"', '\"')
'{"a": "1", "b": "2"}' 

l.replace('\"', '\\"')
'{\\"a\\": \\"1\\", \\"b\\": \\"2\\"}'
```

How do I convert `{\"a\": \"1\", \"b\": \"2\"}`?

Comment: commonly the first argument of a replace string is the value you want to change and the second is what you want to change it to. in this case you want to change `l.replace('"', '\"')` to get the desired result

Comment: It also returns '{"a": "1", "b": "2"}'

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886596/replace-all-quotes-in-a-string-with-escaped-quotes

Comment: oh I forgot that Python sees a \ as the next character a physical character which means it needs a double backslash to get the result, sorry about that @McGrady is correct :)

Comment: you have to escape the slash with slash, `'\\' + '"'` or simply `'\\"'`

Comment: Your second `replace` call is working, you're just seeing the `repr` of the result (which doubles the backslashes).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
print l.replace('"','\\"')
```

`'\"'` doesn't mean anything special to Python, so you needn't to add `\` before `"`,if you run

`print l.replace('\"', '\\"')`,you will get a single backslash too.

Actually what you are seeing is the representation of the string, it's added by [**repr**()](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method.Python represents backslashes in strings as `\\` because the backslash is an [Escape Character](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) .

If you print it, you will  get single backslash.

You can see more information from [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: Or `print(l.replace('"','\\"'))` if you are not using an old/legacy version of Python.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this also

```
print l.replace('"',r'\"')
```

or

```
print l.replace('"','\\"')
```