# How can we replace quotation marks in a string in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string causing a bit of a problem. This is my string.

```
my_string = "'{'place_id': X, 'licence': 'X', 'osm_type': 'X', 'osm_id': X,'boundingbox': X, 'lat': 'X', 'lon': 'X', 'display_name': 'X', 'class': 'X', 'type': 'X','importance': X})'"
```

If I don't have `"'` at the beginning and `'"` at the end, it's not treated as a string.

Maybe I am creating the string the wrong way. Not sure. Anyway, this is what I end up with.

```
["'{'place_id': X, 'licence': 'X', 'osm_type': 'X'}'",
{'place_id': 177948251,
  'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
  'osm_type': 'way'},
{'place_id': 306607940,
  'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
  'osm_type': 'way'}]
```

I'm trying to convert this list to a dataframe but I'm getting this error:

`'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys''`

I think the problem comes from the first item in the list having this:

`"'` and `'"`

So, I tried to do a str.replace on the items in the list, like this.

```
new_strings = []
for j in final_list:
   new_string = str.replace("""'{""", "{") 
   new_string = str.replace("""}'""", "}")
   new_strings.append(new_string)
   
my_df = pd.DataFrame(new_string)
```

When I try to run that, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-83-424d9a0504f8>", line 3, in <module>
    new_string = str.replace("""'{""","{")

TypeError: replace expected at least 2 arguments, got 1
```

Any idea how to get this straightened out?

Comment: You need to tell it to replace j in the loop.

Comment: Try using backslash like `"\""`

Comment: Whatever generated those strings should probably be changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace all quotes in a string with escaped quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886596/replace-all-quotes-in-a-string-with-escaped-quotes)

Comment: You do not have some strings, you have one string and two dicts. You can probably convert that first string to a dict, but my advice would be to figure out how you got into this mess in the first place, and then not do that.

Comment: That string is a mess. It's like a Python `dict` literal wrapped in a string wrapped in another string. Unravelling it will be fragile, since the single quotes don't nest.

Comment: I just made a small update to my original post. If I can create my_string in a better way, like without the extra quotation marks, I think the problem will fade away.

Comment: Seems like u just want to access the python `dict`, whih is wrapped by quotation marks twice. Try `a = eval ('the-string-which-is-actually-a-dict')`

Comment: Try like this `print(eval("'{'place_id': 'X', 'licence': 'X', 'osm_type': 'X'}'"[1:-1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps you. Note that I putted ' around X as I think it is a typo in the original one.

```
import json

old_list = [
    "'{'place_id': 'X', 'licence': 'X', 'osm_type': 'X'}'",
    {
        'place_id': 177948251,
        'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
        'osm_type': 'way'
    },
    {
        'place_id': 306607940,
        'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
        'osm_type': 'way'
    }
]

new_list = []
for item in old_list:
    if isinstance(item, str):
        # if we strip the surrounding ' and replace all other ' with "
        # this looks like a json document
        item_json = item.strip("'").replace("'", '"')
        item_dict = json.loads(item_json)
        new_list.append(item_dict)
    elif isinstance(item, dict):
        # perfect, we can keep this item as it is
        new_list.append(item)
    else:
        # oh oh, we got an unexpected type
        raise TypeError
```

Comment: It's working now! Thanks everyone!!