# Python escape quotes in a given string variable

Tags: python, string, escaping

I have to run a command in the command line that is structured as follows:

```
"C:/..." --input="{THE INPUT}"
```

My problem is that the input is code and therefore contains quotes.
Imagine the input being `printf("test")`, that would screw up my command.
This is why the input in this case would need to be `printf(\"test\")`

I tried the following:

```
test = 'printf("test")'
test2 = test.replace('"', '\"')
test3 = test.replace('"', '\\"')
command = f'"c:/..." --input="{test}"'
command2 = f'"c:/..." --input="{test2}"'
command3 = f'"c:/..." --input="{test2}"'
```

I run the command like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.getoutput(command)
```

test and test2 contain `printf("test")`, test3 contains `printf(\\"test\\")`

But what I need is `printf(\"test\")`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `shlex.quote()`

Comment: Are you making a system call from your program?  Then I think the answer to your question may be differ between operating systems and maybe between shells.

Comment: Instead of creating the command as a string, it's generally preferable to use `subprocess` and send the command as a list. Then no quoting is needed.

Comment: Here is a similar question and answer.  _https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886596/replace-all-quotes-in-a-string-with-escaped-quotes_.

Answer (score 0):

Try `shlex`

```
import shlex

test = 'printf("test")'
escaped_test = shlex.quote(test)
command = f'"C:/..." --input={escaped_test}'

print(command)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this results in `\'printf("test")\'`