# Python double quotation syntax issue

Tags: python, html, syntax-error, quotation-marks

This is my code:

```
for i in range(0, row_count):
    if counter<row_count-1:
        lines.append(""" var flightPlanCoordinates = [
                {lat:""" + latitude[i] + """, lng: """ + longitude[i] + """}
                {lat:""" + latitude[i + 1] + """, lng: """ + longitude[i + 1] + """}
            ];
            """)
        lines.append("""var flightPath"""+i+""" = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 5
            });""")
        counter += 1
```

I'm trying to figure out why this isn't compiling(I'm getting a syntax error). This is a string that will be part of the code to an html page. I want to create i flight path variables, each named flightpathi. So flightpath0, flightpath1 and so forth. When using """+i+""" or any other variable inside triple quotations on other lines, this works. I know this is probably something pretty simple that I'm overlooking, but I'm stuck and I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Triple quotes are for multiline comments in python. I would use `"var flightPath" + str(i)`. You may also want to look into [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for your loop. If you need the extra quotes as part of your string for some reason you need to escape them so they are not comments.

Comment: Thank you. And how can I escape them so they aren't comments ?

Comment: Here is post about it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275762/escaping-quotes-in-string I would read the selected answer and the comments as there are some caveats when escaping quotes